# Replacing PasteSpecial Pastvalues with more effiecient code

Tags: excel, vba

Can I make the below more efficient as I have about 20 cases like below in the code I am looking at ?

```
RowItem = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("ListA")) - 2

Range("Full_list").Resize(RowItem + 2).Copy
Range("Full_list").Offset(0, 1 + i).Resize(RowItem + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: "Efficient" means less lines of code, or quicker run-time?

Comment: The latter please and less prone to error, please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim RowItem As Long, i As Long
RowItem = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("ListA")) - 2
' i =   ' i must be assigned a value
With Range("Full_list").Resize(RowItem + 2)
    .Offset(0, 1 + i).Value = .Value
End With
```

I wish you had given more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with the worksheet directly will always be slower than storing your data in memory.

```
Private Sub Example()

    ' Store data in array
    Dim arrayA() As Variant
    arrayA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value2

    ' Count the number of rows in the array
    ' Notice we are NOT using the WorksheetFunction
    Dim rangeCount As Long
    rangeCount = UBound(arrayA, 1) - LBound(arrayA, 1) + 1

    ' Write the data to the sheet
    ' Notice we are NOT using .Copy and .Paste
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D4").Value = arrayA
    
End Sub
```

This is a simplified version of what you're doing.  The concepts are all shown, and should be easily transferable to your problem.

I can't quantify exactly how much faster this will be, but my rough testing shows it's at least 100 times faster than the alternative method of using `.Copy` and `.Paste`.

If arrays are new to you, I recommend taking some time to learn about them.  They're quite useful.

Comment: Note that `arrayA` corresponds to 10 rows and you're assigning it to a 4-row range.

Comment: @BigBen You're right.  I should've made a note about that.  Reasoning was that OP's `ListA` and `Full_list` seemed to be different sizes, so I wanted to keep that in my example.  Possible that it adds more confusion, however.